# Resolving resource values in custom lint rule

Tags: android, lint, android-lint

I have a large Android codebase and I am writing a custom lint rule that checks whether the values of certain attributes fall within a given range.

For example, I have this component:

```
<MyCustomComponent
    my:animation_factor="0.7"
    ...>
</MyCustomComponent>
```

and I want to write a lint rule that alerts developers that values of `my:animation_factor` >= 1 should be used with caution.

I followed the instructions at http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules and managed to retrieve the value of `my:animation_factor` using this code:

```
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.*;

public class XmlInterpolatorFactorTooHighDetector {

    ....
    @Override
    public Collection<String> getApplicableElements() {
        return ImmutableList.of("MyCustomComponent");
    }

    @Override
    public void visitElement(XmlContext context, Element element) {
        String factor = element.getAttribute("my:animation_factor");
        ...
        if (value.startsWith("@dimen/")) {
            // How do I resolve @dimen/xyz to 1.85?
        } else {
            String value = Float.parseFloat(factor);
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine when attributes such as `my:animation_factor` have literal values (e.g. `0.7`).

However, when the attribute value is a resources (e.g. `@dimen/standard_anim_factor`) then `element.getAttribute(...)` returns the string value of the attribute instead of the actual resolved value.

For example, when I have a `MyCustomComponent` that looks like this:

```
<MyCustomComponent
    my:animation_factor="@dimen/standard_anim_factory"
    ...>
</MyCustomComponent>
```

and `@dimen/standard_anim_factor` is defined elsewhere:

```
<dimen name="standard_anim_factor">1.85</dimen>
```

then the string `factor` becomes "@dimen/standard_anim_factor" instead of "1.85".

Is there a way to resolve "@dimen/standard_anim_factor" to the actual value of resource (i.e. "1.85") while processing the `MyCustomComponent` element?

Comment: Unable to understand your question, if you are getting value `0.7` then how come it point towards `standard_anim_factor` or if it is pointing towards it what is the issue ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I edited the question to make it more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general problem with the resolution of values is, that they depend on the Android runtime context you are in. There might be several `values` folders with different concrete values for your key `@dimen/standard_anim_factory`, so just that you are aware of.

Nevertheless, AFAIK there exist two options:

- Perform a two phase detection:

  - **Phase 1: Scan your resources**
  - Scan for your attribute and put it in a list (instead of evaluating it immediately)
  - Scan your dimension values and put them in a list as well
  - **Phase 2:**
  - override `Detector.afterProjectCheck` and resolve your attributes by iterating over the two lists filled within phase 1
- usually the `LintUtils` class [1] is a perfect spot for that stuff but unfortunately there is no method which resolves dimensions values. However, there is a method called `getStyleAttributes` which demonstrates how to resolve resource values. So you could write your own convenient method to resolve dimension values:

```
    private int resolveDimensionValue(String name, Context context){
       LintClient client = context.getDriver().getClient();
       LintProject project = context.getDriver().getProject();
       AbstractResourceRepository resources = client.getProjectResources(project, true);

       return Integer.valueOf(resources.getResourceItem(ResourceType.DIMEN, name).get(0).getResourceValue(false).getValue());
    }
```

**Note:** I haven't tested the above code yet. So please see it as theoretical advice :-)

1. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/lint/libs/lint-api/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/detector/api/LintUtils.java

Just one more slight advice for your custom Lint rule code, since you are only interested in the attribute:

Instead of doing something like this in `visitElement`:

```
String factor = element.getAttribute("my:animation_factor");
```

...you may want to do something like this:

```
@Override
public Collection<String> getApplicableAttributes() {
    return ImmutableList.of("my:animation_factor");
}

@Override    
void visitAttribute(@NonNull XmlContext context, @NonNull Attr attribute){
    ...
}
```

But it's just a matter of preference :-)

Comment: The 2-phase approach definitely solves the problem without requiring too much work at runtime. It's a shame that Android Lint doesn't have a better interface (or just a better template) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking looking for `getResources().getDimension()`.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimension%28int%29

Comment: The problem is that `getResources()` is a method of `android.content.Context` but Lint uses a `com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Context` that has no method for getting/resolving resources.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming xml node after parsing your data, try the following

```
Element element = null; //It is your root node.
NamedNodeMap attrib = (NamedNodeMap) element;

int numAttrs = attrib.getLength ();

for (int i = 0; i < numAttrs; i++) {
    Attr attr = (Attr) attrib.item (i);

    String attrName = attr.getNodeName ();
    String attrValue = attr.getNodeValue ();

    System.out.println ("Found attribute: " + attrName + " with value: " + attrValue);

}
```

Comment: Thanks Murtaza but this just prints `Found attribute: my:animation_factor with value: @dimen/standard_anim_factory` which is what I already had... I wanted it to print  `Found attribute: my:animation_factor with value: 1.85`.

Comment: it means you need to reiterate it, Hope you understand what I am trying to say. if you found the node then reiterate it that element.